# How to set full width image in footer of pdf in tcpdf library codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf, tcpdf

I'm using the TCPDF library to create a `.pdf` file. I have to add an image in the footer which should cover 100% of the width, but it's coming in the center with equal margin from left and right. I want to remove those margins and set full width to the footer image. The code I'm using to set the footer is below. You can also see in the attach image how my image appears in the footer:-

```
$footer_image_file = './images/logo/footer.png';
$footer_logo_html = '<div style="width:100opx !important;height:100px;"><img width:"1000px;" src="' . $footer_image_file . '" /></div>';
$pdf->writeHTML($footer_logo_html, true, 0, true, 0);
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try use [`writeHTMLCell()`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rfpdf/1.17.1/TCPDF%3AwriteHTMLCell) for this. Set 1st parameter `21` - A4 width (I set `cm` as unit of measure), and 4 as A4 height - image height:

```
$pdf->writeHTMLCell(21, '', 0, 29.7 - 4, $footer_logo_html, 0, 1, false, true, 'L', false);
```

Result:

[image]

I use Your `.png`, so it have white space on the edges =)

Comment: OMG! They broke good documentation... Again. @Curious - thanks, updated;